# "Modern Script Editor Feature" not available for activation from site features page

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, spfx, modern-experience, script-webpart

In SharePoint Online, I want to activate "Modern Script Editor Feature" from Site features page but it is not visible/available.

How to enable this feature for activation?

The below screenshot is from a Tenant where this feature is available but this feature is missing in my tenant

[image]

Comment: I don't see any modern script editor site feature in my tenant as well. Is this any custom feature developed by developers in your company? If Yes, you have to deploy it to another tenant as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are tying to use classic feature of SharePoint in SharePoint online.

SharePoint online site script editor web part is not available by default. In order to make it available, we need to enable the custom script from the SharePoint Tenant admin center.

You can enable it by going to below URL

_layouts/15/online/TenantSettings.aspx

Now select to allow users to run the custom script for both the radio button for below given Option.

Allow users from running custom script on personal sites.
Allow users from running custom script on self-service created sites)

after this setting You have to wait for 24 hours after that custom script will be enable on your site

Answer (score 0):

There is no "Modern Script Editor Feature" in SharePoint online.

If you are referring to Modern script editor web parts developed using SPFx then check below samples:

1. [react-script-editor](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor)
2. [Modern CEWP by SPJS](https://spjsblog.com/modern-cewp/)

Or if you are talking about allowing custom scripts in SharePoint online, check below Microsoft official documentation:

[Allow or prevent custom script](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/allow-or-prevent-custom-script)